# Comparing elements of char*

Tags: c, pointers

EDIT: it works i just had strings with '/n' right before the '/0'

Hello i am new to programming in C and have a question:
Why does this not work to get the return value 1 for strings with same char in first and last position:

```
function1(char* str){
   if(str[0]==str[strlen(str)-1]){
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
   }
```

EDIT: solution in my case was that in my string there was an invisible element before \0,  so that the last visual char had the index strlen(str)-2.

Comment: random_noob, What if `str` is `""`.  What do you expect with `str[0]==str[strlen(str)-1]`?

Comment: except for corner cases, make it return an `int`? Looks like [it works](https://godbolt.org/z/j9vT81GEj) to me

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I expect to get the first char of the string with str[0] and the last with str[strlen(str)-1]. Is this wrong? I tried and it seems to work. For example for abca i get a and a. However it seems that a != a...

Comment: random_noob, what is the _last character_ of _string_ `""`?

Comment: @yano ok now im really confused i will double check why it wont work in my code.

Comment: Thank all of you for your help!

Comment: Using the -2 in the index will compare with the second-to-last character, not the last character.  If you are seeing that work (when -1 doesn't), most likely your string has an extra character on the end of it; perhaps a newline?

Comment: @ChrisDodd my char* has \0 at the end, maybe that is why...it works fine with -2 i tested it for many different strings

Comment: The \0 is the terminator, which will be (by definition) at `str[strlen(str)]`.  so `str[strlen(str)-1]` will always be the last character (the one immediately before the \0), and `str[strlen(str)-2]` will be the one before that.  Your testing just shows that you are consistently getting an extra "invisible" character on the end (between what you think is the last character and the \0) -- probably a \n or \r

Comment: @ChrisDodd ok i understand, but i get all my strings from stdin, so i wonder how this invisible char sneaks in, is it because i press enter maybe?. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Yes, if you use `fgets`, you strings will (pretty much) always end with \n characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://onlinegdb.com/1FMelNgUj-) works:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int function1(char* str)
{
    if(!(strlen(str) == 0))
    {
        if(str[0] == str[strlen(str)-1])
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
   
int main()
{
    printf("I am same: %i\n", function1("HaH"));
    printf("I am not same: %i\n", function1("HaR"));
    return 0;
}
```

- You're missing a return type for your function :)
  EDIT: Also, you should take care if the `str` is empty or not.

Comment: `str[strlen(str)-1]` is certainly _undefined behavior_ when `*s == 0`.

Comment: `if(!strlen(str) == 0)` - too complicated.

Comment: OK, `!strlen(str) == 0` seems like an expensive way to test `*str == 0`, but UV for the improvement.